# Delete duplicate records in hive on the basis of a condition

Tags: hive

My hive table company is as follow:

| Comp_id | comp_isin | date | value | version | insert_tms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coco cola | Abc123 | 2022-06-12 | 13 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |
| Coco cola | Abc123 | 2022-06-12 | 13 | v2 | 2022-06-12 05:32:25 |
| Baskin | BR456 | 2022-06-12 | 5 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |
| havmor | HV567 | 2022-06-12 | 5 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |
| havmor | HV567 | 2022-06-12 | 5 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |

Table specs : Comp_id, comp_isin, date - this is one row subject that means there can only be a row for an id, isin, and date.

So, the table company has data like above. V1 and v2 indicate that the data arrived with the corrected version in v2. But, the v1 record is retained in the table.

I need to update the table in HIVE for all the below conditions:

1. Delete v1 records if there is a v2 for that id, isin and date (ex : coco cola v1 needs to get deleted)
2. Delete duplicate records (ex havmor)
3. Rest remains untouched

I created another table and tried distinct with where condition on version but that also removed records without duplicates.

Insert overwrite is confusing as the conditions are particular.

I needed the above table as

| Comp_id | comp_isin | date | value | version | insert_tms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Coco cola | Abc123 | 2022-06-12 | 13 | v2 | 2022-06-12 05:32:25 |
| Baskin | BR456 | 2022-06-12 | 5 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |
| havmor | HV567 | 2022-06-12 | 5 | v1 | 2022-06-12 00:45:23 |

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use a window function like below.

```sql
SELECT comp_id, comp_isin, `date`, value, version, insert_tms FROM (
  SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY comp_id, comp_isin, `date` 
               ORDER BY insert_tms DESC
         ) rn
    FROM company
) t WHERE rn = 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]